Today I bought 5000013 $WEPE coin using ETH in Presale event but I don't see in wallet. In place of getting WEPE coin ETH got swap with very small ETH
Transaction Hx: - 0x99613dd6d61bc578cdac6fe42954d837f8b877244d11ba4ae494e37da8f69cef
Please help.

Your token balance was located by this function 
Not by function balanceOf. So wallet extension or etherscan can't see your balance. It's a standard of token by using balanceOf to determine balance token.
The address you're interacting isn't treated as a token. For example, if a smart contract is a token contract, etherscan can recognize and display Token tracker like this 
